# Application to read from Facebook wall

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am building a Customer Contact Center application, which will monitor my client's Facebook page.

Their end customers write their complaints on their Facebook wall. I need to write an application which will monitor the wall for new messages.  Whenever a new message comes, it will initiate a work-item in my BPM system.

My core application is in Java and supports MS-SQL and Oracle databases as backend. Please advise me on how should I go about this work.

Answer (score 0):

There is [facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) by which you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response Harish. But isn't the Java API about to be deprecated? I am not very particular about Java. I can build it in any other language too, which will make entries in a database. My application will read from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [restfb](http://restfb.com/) to utilize Java for accessing Facebook.